# Loading of scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I'm don't well in English and smth can write with mistakes & I'm beginner in programming that is why I want to ask you: why some functions execute before the page load when you localize your JS file at the top of ? I don't understand why them execute whereas I have not caused them yet.

Sorry for my English :C

Comment: Because code is executed when something executes it?  Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Could You show us your HTML/Javascript? Also for the English Part, try Grammarly :)

Comment: there is no problem in grammer we speak code in her, show as what you have in your .html and .js

Comment: Thanks for all of you, guys. I have got answer for my question. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really up to you if you want to execute your function after load the whole page you can do it. if you use jquery u can  create this block which will execute ur function just after your page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // code will goes here
});
```

Comment: Its ok . we all are here to help each other